# Cross product calculation for showing that the cross product is not associative

Tags: cross-product

I am trying to show that the cross product is not associative, using the vectors $\mathbf{A} = (5, 3, 1), \mathbf{B} = (1, 2, 3), \mathbf{C} = (4, 2, 1)$.

Using the determinants method, I get

$$\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B} = [(3)(3) - (1)(2)]\mathbf{\hat{i}} - [(5)(3) - (1)(1)]\mathbf{\hat{j}} + [(5)(2) - (3)(1)]\mathbf{\hat{k}} = (7, 14, 7)$$

$$(\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}) \times \mathbf{C} = [(14)(1) - (7)(2)]\mathbf{\hat{i}} - [(7)(1) - (7)(4)]\mathbf{\hat{j}} + [(7)(2) - (14)(4)]\mathbf{\hat{k}} = (0, 21, -42)$$

According to this [document](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/105Sp11/extracredit/ExtraCredit_AssocCrossProd.pdf), $(\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}) \times \mathbf{C}$ should be $(−28, 21, 70)$. I would greatly appreciate it if someone would please take the time to explain what I did incorrectly.

Comment: Check the signs. Hint: the middle value is correct.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I did. The order is $+$ for $\mathbf{\hat{i}}$, $-$ for $\mathbf{\hat{j}}$, and $+$ for $\mathbf{\hat{k}}$, right?

Comment: $\mathbf A\times \mathbf B=(7,\color{red}-14,7)$

Comment: Yes. Check again.

Comment: $\newcommand{\e}{\mathbf{e}}\newcommand{\0}{\mathbf{0}}\newcommand{\a}{\mathbf{a}}\newcommand{\b}{\mathbf{b}}$By the way, if you just want to show that the cross product is not associative, there are easier examples you could use, e.g. using the standard basis vectors for $\Bbb{R}^3$: $$\e_1 \times (\e_1 \times \e_2) = \e_1\times \e_3\ne \0,$$ whereas $$(\e_1\times \e_1)\times \e_2 = \0\times \e_2 = \0.$$ (Facts used here include that $\a\times \b = \0$ iff $\a$ and $\b$ are linearly dependent ("parallel"), and $\e_1\times \e_2=\e_3$.)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh, I see it now. Thanks!

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Oh, yes, just using the standard basis vectors would be simpler.